How to display current log entry count in Grafana/Loki graph per day
Similar to this question, I am trying to aggregate Grafana Loki logs per day (provided by Serilog) so that I can view a vertical bar chart (or line, TBD) of errors per day.  An error will be denoted by the log level ("level" in the JSON data) being Warning, Error or Fatal.  My data json looks like:
{Message:"Message goes here",MessageTemplate:"Message goes here","level":"info"}
This is my query:
sum(count_over_time({ApplicationName="MyAppName"} | json | level="info"[1d]))
And I set Type to Range and Step to 1d, but everything for the current day is not displayed.  I want to also show current day as they come in.  What am I missing?  Ideally I want it to look like this just with it showing the current day as the logs come in

I don't think this is possible to do (on the same panel). Please see how step works in Prometheus. I think it's reasonable to assume it works similarly in the Loki.

But on separate panel you can set relative time to now/d and get result's for "so far today"
